# killed with gun vs killed by gun difference(Which is more natural or both are correct)?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

On a language learning app I corrected someones following sentence

**I'm afraid I will be killed with gun.**
to
**I'm afraid I will be killed by a gun.**
But then he told me we can also use with for the same. I though use of with instead of by in this sentence is a little unnatural sounding.

Do native speaker use with instead of by in this case?

Comment: Hi ashish, you may not realise that English Language & Usage (EL&U) is a question and answer site for *linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts*. For your reference, note that our other site [ell.se] offers a wealth of information that's useful for both native speakers and learners. FWIW, you can be killed *with* a gun **or** *by* a gun.

Comment: Both would be very informal and somewhat confusing. ... *will die from a gunshot wound* would be better. Or just *I'm afraid I will be shot.*

Comment: Relevant - AP Style guide - https://writingexplained.org/ap-style/ap-style-homicide-murder-manslaughter.

Comment: Your first sentence is missing the article "a" between "with" and "gun".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Person A was killed Person B with a gun. In this sentence, Person A was doing the killing, and he used a gun to do it.

Person C was killed by a gun. In this sentence the gun did the killing. Obviously this isn't strictly possible, but this is a common way of speaking in English.

So both your bolded sentences are valid, except that the first one needs the indefinite article "a" added. The difference between the two is who does the killing.

Comment: You really can't get there with *killed*. Use a different verb, like *shot* or *died*.

Answer (score 1):

Most native speakers would probably just say:

> I'm afraid I will be shot (to death / and killed).

---

Note that both of your sentences are open to different interpretations than what you intend.

> **I'm afraid I will be killed with a gun.**

This could be interpreted to mean:

> I'm afraid that I will be killed and I will have a gun with me.

Here, it is only talking about the fact that you are carrying a gun at the time of your murder.

---

> **I'm afraid I will be killed by a gun.**

This could be interpreted to mean:

> I'm afraid that somebody will club me to death with a gun.

In this case, it doesn't mean that you will be *shot* but simply that the gun will be used as the murder weapon.

Or:

> I'm afraid that somebody will kill me when I'm standing next to a gun.

Here, *by* is used in the sense of *in proximity to*.

Or in a modern fantasy world where magic is possible:

> I'm afraid that a gun will come to life and kill me.

Here, it's the gun itself doing the killing rather than it just being used as the tool of murder by somebody else.

---

There are ways of rephrasing both sentences so that there isn't room for these other interpretations.

But the words *with* and *by* have different meanings. Those different meanings should be considered.

Comment: Your alternative interpretations are all possible, but none of them are the first thing that would come to mind on reading the phrases.

Comment: @AndyT But the issues would, at least in the US, where any attempt to blame the gun will  guarantee  a ruckus.